# Extending partial sums of the Taylor series of $e^x$ to a smooth function on $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: special-functions, taylor-expansion, gamma-function

Is there a smooth function $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x,n)$, where $n\in\mathbb{N}$, is the truncated Taylor series of $e^x$, namely $1+ x + \frac{x^2}{2} + \dotsb + \frac{x^n}{n!}$, in a fashion similar to the gamma function?

Comment: You probably mean not only smooth but analytic?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure; we have the relationship

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{x^k}{k!}=\frac{\Gamma(n+1,x)}{\Gamma(n+1)}\exp\,x=Q(n+1,x)\exp\,x$$

where $\Gamma(n)$ is the usual gamma function and $\Gamma(n,a)$ is the [(upper) incomplete gamma function](http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.2.E2), and $Q(n,a)$ is the regularized (upper) incomplete gamma function; see that link as well as [this link](http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Gamma2/) for more on its properties. The expression on the right definitely makes sense not only for integer values of $n$...

Comment: Is there a "name" for this type of interpolation?  Many interpolating function for truncated series can be found by writing $\sum_{k=0}^na_k$ as $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k-\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_{k+n+1}$.  I am curious about the properties of these types of interpolating functions but do not know what to search for.

Comment: Also, is there anything special about this particular interpolation of the partial sum? There are an infinite number of ways to interpolate the partials sum however it seems like this one must have some special properties compared to an arbitrary interpolation.

Comment: There's not really a name for this, but this particular case can either be derived through the recurrence relation for incomplete gamma, or by manipulating finite hypergeometric series.

Comment: Thanks for the response J.M.  I have noted a connection to fractional derivatives and this particular interpolation problem.  What is interesting is that I have seen this connection before in interpolating truncated generalized hypergeometric series.  This question is just a simple case since $e^x={_0F_}(-;-;x)$ so the truncated series can be thought of as a truncated hypergeometric series as well.  I wonder why these two concepts (interpolation and fractional calculus) are showing up in these types of problems. Interesting.

Answer (score 2):

This is meant as a compliment to J.M.'s answer but the interpolation provided has a connection to fractional derivatives. Specifically,
$$
(1-D_x^{-(\nu+1)})e^x = e^x Q(\nu+1,x),
$$
where $D_x^\alpha$ is interpreted to  be the Riemann-Liouville fractional derivative w.r.t. the variable $x$. This is easily seen by first expanding $e^x$ as a power series to write
$$
(1-D_x^{-(\nu+1)})e^x%
=e^x-\sum_{k=0}^\infty D_x^{-(\nu+1)}\frac{x^k}{k!}%
=e^x-\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\Gamma(k+1)}{\Gamma(\nu+k+2)}\frac{x^{k+\nu+1}}{k!}.
$$
Then, with a bit of algebraic manipulation we obtain
$$
(1-D_x^{-(\nu+1)})e^x%
=e^x-\frac{z^{\nu+1}}{\Gamma(\nu+2)}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(1)_k}{(\nu+2)_k}\frac{x^k}{k!}%
=e^x-\frac{z^{\nu+1}}{\Gamma(\nu+2)}{_1F_1}(1,\nu+2,x)=e^x-e^x P(\nu+1,x)=e^xQ(\nu+1,x),
$$
where $(a)_k=\Gamma(a+k)/\Gamma(a)$ is the Pochhammer symbol and $P(z,s)$ is the regularized (lower) incomplete gamma function.

EDIT: So I did a little more digging and came across the article [Expansion of fractional derivatives in terms of an integer derivative series](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.06297)

Equation $(15)$ for $a=0$ gives the following integer derivative expansion of the Riemann-Liouville fractional derivative
$$
D_x^\alpha=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{\alpha}{k}\frac{x^{k-\alpha}}{\Gamma(k-\alpha+1)}D_x^k.
$$
If we treat this expansion as a traditional power series we find
$$
D_x^\alpha=x^{-\alpha}{_1\mathbf F_1}(-\alpha,1-\alpha,-xD_x),
$$
where ${_1\mathbf F_1}(a;b;z)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(b)}{_1F_1}(a;b;z)$ is the regularized confluent hypergeometric function of the first kind. Since $D_x^k \,e^x=e^x\ \forall\, k\in\Bbb N_0$ the derivative is evaluated to be
$$
\begin{aligned}
(1-D_x^{-(\nu+1)})e^x%
&=e^x-x^{-\alpha}{_1\mathbf F_1}(\nu+1,\nu+2,-xD_x)e^x\\
&=e^x-x^{\nu+1}{_1\mathbf F_1}(\nu+1,\nu+2,-x)e^x\\
&=e^x(1-P(\nu+1,x))\\
&=e^xQ(\nu+1,x).
\end{aligned}
$$