# "Natural" interpolation between partial sums of a power series

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

Suppose $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$ has a radius of convergence of $R$. Let the $N$-th partial sum be $f_N (z)=\sum_{n=0}^N a_n z^n$. What smooth (analytic) function interpolates between $f_N(z)$. In other words what "natural" analytic function $F(\alpha,z)$ has the property that $F(N,z)=f_N(z)$ for $N=0,1,\cdots$.

[Related Question for $f=e^z$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/125781/extending-partial-sums-of-the-taylor-series-of-ex-to-a-smooth-function-on-m)

Comment: How about $\sum_0^{\infty}a_n{\alpha\choose n}z^n$, where $\alpha\choose n$ is $\alpha(\alpha-1)\cdots(\alpha-n+1)/n!$?

Comment: This does not get truncated at $N$. I am looking for something in the spirit of generalization of factorial to gamma function. One guesses that some sort of integral operator is involved. It could be that my question does not have enough constraints to give a unique answer.

Comment: If $\alpha=N$, then all the terms with $n\gt N$ are zero, so I don't see what you mean by "This does not get truncated at $N$."

Comment: @GerryMyerson My mistake. This is interesting but If I understand this correctly for $N=3$ for example we get $F(3,z)=a_0 {3 \choose 0}+a_1 {3 \choose 1} z + a_2 { 3 \choose 2}z^2 + a_3 {3 \choose 3} z^3=a_0+3a_1 z+3a_2 z^2+a_3 z^3$. It is kind of a dot product of series with the binomials and that does not give partial sums of $f$.

Answer (score 1):

If $a_k$ happens to be a continuous function in $k$, say $a(k)$, one could introduce a parameter $\omega$ and define
$$
f(z,\omega)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a(k+\omega)\, z^k,
$$
where $f(z):=f(z,0)$. Introducing the parameter $n\in\Bbb N_0$ we could then express the the truncated series in the question as
$$
f_n(z)=\sum_{k=0}^na(k)\,z^k.
$$
Now writing the sum as the difference of series (assuming convergence of series) yields
$$
f_n(z)=\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty-\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\right)a(k)\,z^k=f(z)-z^{n+1}\sum_{n=0}^\infty a(k+n+1)\,z^k=f(z)-z^{n+1}f(z,n+1).
$$
We can now relax the assumption $n\in\Bbb N_0$ to find an interpolation of $f_n$.

As a simple example consider the truncated geometric series
$$
f_n(z)=\sum_{k=0}^n z^k.
$$
Clearly, $a(k)=1$ is continuous everywhere so we write the interpolation function as
$$
f_\nu(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty z^k-z^{\nu+1}\sum_{k=0}^\infty z^k=\frac{1}{1-z}-z^{\nu+1}\frac{1}{1-z}=\frac{1-z^{\nu+1}}{1-z},
$$
which provides an interpolation for $|z|<1$ and $\nu\in\Bbb C$.